# High Request Charge and Index lookup time in Cosmos DB (SQL API)

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I am using Cosmos DB (SQL API) with partitionKey defined. A container with different types of items. When I query DB with a specific filter and an ORDER BY clause, Request Charge and Index lookup are really high, what could be the problem? Thanks.

Indexing Policy:

```
{
"indexingMode": "consistent",
"automatic": true,
"includedPaths": [
    {
        "path": "/*"
    }
],
"excludedPaths": [
    {
        "path": "/\"_etag\"/?"
    }
]
```

}

Query:

SELECT * FROM c WHERE c.tipo = "tipo-registro" ORDER BY c._ts DESC

Request Charge: 106358.29899999998 RUs
Index lookup time: 23253.1198 ms

[image]

Without ORDER BY clause:
[image]

Item sample:

```
{
    "tipo": "tipo-registro",
    "partitionKey": "111122222",
    "frame": "100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
    "numserie": "111122222",
    "processed": true,
    "registered": true,
    "id": "af1b1ec8-9cd5-4e59-87bb-ae339607a761",
    "_rid": "S0lbA456qyEoJ+0AAAAAAA==",
    "_self": "dbs/S0lbAA==/colls/S0lb456123E=/docs/S0lbAK3QqyEoJ+0AAAAAAA==/",
    "_etag": "\"b7001012b-1111-0d00-0000-6098fe470000\"",
    "_attachments": "attachments/",
    "_ts": 1620639303
}
```

Comment: Try creating a composite index on _ts. you can find examples here, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/how-to-manage-indexing-policy?tabs=dotnetv2%2Cpythonv3#composite-index

Comment: you can also learn more by checking out this video, skip to 10:20 in. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y3L7TRUP4sE&t=1469s

Comment: Aside from composite indexes, you haven't mentioned anything about partitioning.  Is it possible your query is spanning multiple physical partitions? Maybe # of partitions, combined with # of documents, adds to the RU cost?

Comment: Composite index, ok, I will apply. Anyway, these high RUs didnt happen untill two weeks ago with this query, maybe could be a partitioning problem? This type of item has differents partitionKey values depends of device which are associate of, so could be possible they are spaning multiple physical partitions... how can I check physical partitions distribution? Thanks all.

Comment: When developing your solutions, don't focus on physical partitions because you can't control them. Here's the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/partitioning-overview#physical-partitions).  And @MarkBrown answered a question related to physical partition [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67346639/some-questions-about-cosmos-db-physical-and-logical-partitions), I think you may find more on it.