# Prevent Cosmos DB from splitting physical partition

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

Suppose we start off with a Cosmos DB collection consisting of a single physical partition. Is it guaranteed that the partition will not be split into multiple physical partitions as long as

- the collection size stays below the limit for physical partitions (currently 50 GB), and
- the provisioned throughput always remains <= 10,000 RU/s?

I am asking because I found [Mark Brown's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67348730/689923) about provisioning a new partition at 60% (of what?) a bit confusing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It isn't guaranteed.

The partition will split sometime **before** you get up to 50GB.

Assuming that your storage remains well below that and that you currently have exactly one partition then you can scale up to 10K without incurring partition splits though - at least as far as current behaviour of the product is.

What Mark's answer is referring to is a different heuristic at creation time compared to every other time.

If you provision a new collection with initial 10,000 manual RU you will be allocated two physical partitions.

This is because the calculation used then is [`CEILING(ProvisionedRU/6000)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/scaling-provisioned-throughput-best-practices#step-3-calculate-the-number-of-rus-to-start-with-for-all-partitions)

So to get a single partition at creation time either provision it with autoscale max of <= 10K or manual throughput of <= 6K.

And then you can scale to manual 10K if desired subsequently.

When you scale up an existing container you will only get RU based partition splits if the new ProvisionedRU/Max Autoscale RU would be > 10000 * number of physical partitions that already exist.

The Portal has recently been enhanced to show where scaling up would cause a partition split - e.g. for a collection with 80 physical partitions I see that I can scale up to 800,000 "instantly" as no splits are needed to support that throughput.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I guess the natural follow-up question then is: which size should not be exceeded for a 10,000 RU/s single partition collection in order for it to never split? This is important because partition splitting effectively halves the performance for point reads.

Comment: There isn't a fixed size AFAIK - it depends on the rate of growth. If you are just hammering the collection with inserts then it will split earlier than if the collection is just gradually increasing in size. As it predicts that it will reach 50GB much earlier. Partition splitting doesn't halve the performance for point reads though. Point reads provide a partition key and an ID so they will just be routed to the correct partition. The RU costs for these won't increase as they are not cross partition. Partition splits are negative for cross partition queries or if your work is not evenly...

Comment: ... distributed across the partitions once they are split. Though if you have a hotter physical partition as that is hosting a hotter subset of logical partition key values you can see [Redistribute throughput across partitions - preview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/nosql/distribute-throughput-across-partitions) - rather than just accepting the default 50/50 split of the RU budget

Comment: And another thing to be careful of is if you split again from 2 partitions to 3 physical partitions (e.g. as you scale up to 30K). Then one partition will have 50% of the key space and the other two partitions only 25% of it so one partition will be doing double the work of the others but all have an even split of the RU budget. So in that case it can be better to scale up enough to get 4 partitions. Though the "Redistribute throughput" feature will also help with that when GA